How do I scan my LAN for .local addresses?
I have found out that at least 1 device on my network is advertising itself using a .local address. (my truenas server).
Any PC or laptop on my LAN can just use servername.local to get to the truenas server.
I was wondering if there is a way to scan my LAN for all .local addresses. And if yes how to go about doing it.

Are you on Windows? Try maybe Angry IP Scanner.

If you are on Linux you could use avahi-discover or another similar program to discover other services advertising themselves on your network under .local. Some background information: Avahi

+1. .local names don't actually exist in an observable form absent zero-conf/Avahi/Boniour services like mDNS. you can't really scan for them with an IP scanner, unless your devices are all using 169.254.x.y addresses.
